# 32-bit to 64-bit jvm migration - jboss web application & linux server

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, jboss, jvm, 32bit-64bit

We are migrating our Java EE / JBoss web application currently running on 32-bit linux box & 32-bit JVM to 64-bit linux box & 64-bit JVM.

We analyzed & changed the JVM heap, permgen, stack etc., sizes appropriately. Is that enough or should we consider any other parameters/ make any other changes as a part of the 64bit migration?

We are currently using "jboss-eap-4.3" / "jboss-4.0.5.GA". Do we need to install / upgrade the JBoss server?

Also, can you point me if any other mandatory change that I am missing on 32-bit to 64-bit migration?

Should I check if all the jar files that we use in our application are compatible to 64-bit jvm?

Comment: JBoss EAP has an official compatibility matrix. It is intensively tested against the JVM's it's guaranteed to be compatible with. If unsure, ask Red Hat support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Define **tests** which **cover your use cases**, and run these against both installations
- Define a **load test** scenario, and run it against both installations as well

Management should approve both suites/procedures.

- There should be no need to check .jars for 64-bit compatibility, unless you use JNI. Anyway problems should be revealed by the tests mentioned before.
- Use the **newest stable JBoss version**. Otherwise you could run into problems while trying to get support for an older version.
- Keep your old installation for a certain time to be able to switch back.